# Angularjs Contenteditable in ng-repeat with row/column actions

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have HTML table where its rows and columns are dynamically created by angular js. After a row/column has been added, I would like to have a option that when the user hovers over that row or column it would display a delete button icon clicking which would delete that row/column. For delete column I got it working. So if you see my below demo and hover over to just above top of column you would see a delete icon.

I am having issues with row delete. I want the delete icon to appear to the left of  first row, but it does not appear. The issue is because I am using contenteditable for that row. If I remove that it works and I can see the icon.

```
contenteditable="true"
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
 <td class="unique-id" contenteditable="true" ng-model="r.id">{{r.id}}
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
      <button ng-show="row == $index" type="button" class="btn" ng-click="deleteRow($index)">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
    </div>
</td>
```

Above if I remove contenteditable or make contenteditable="false", I can see the delete icon but not with contenteditable="true". I want to have this row editable so want this property to be true.

Any workarounds to get this resolved or any other solutions.

Below is the codepen demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmBXqg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a work around that you can use. I basically just moved the id to a div instead of the td so both divs can coexist in the td while one has `contenteditable` set to true

```
 <td class="unique-id">
            <div contenteditable="true" ng-model="r.id">{{r.id}}</div>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
              <button ng-show="row == $index" type="button" class="btn" ng-click="deleteRow($index)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
            </div>
          </td>
```

Comment: this does works but the only issue being the action icon is now below the element itself and the width of the row td where the user types has decreased which is not a big issue. But is it possible to have this action button before the data and not below it. Can we somehow create a invisible column and have this action button there? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmBXqg

Comment: put the button in a `span` instead of a `div` and use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`
 this will solve your problem of the icon appearing below

Comment: yeah you need to put the id in a span as well

Comment: Not sure how adding an id would make a difference. Its still the same: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmBXqg

Comment: No. I meant to put the whole id part in a span. here (I finally had to make a codepen account lmao) 
https://codepen.io/jazib_m/pen/mzRdzg

Comment: Thanks that works. FYI you dont need to create an account. You could just fork and save it as anonymous.